# tSNE function is tensorboard and sklearn behave widely different

Tags: scikit-learn, tsne, tensorboard

Perplexity: 20
Learning rate: 10
N_iters: 250

tensorboard returns a scatter plot like this:
[image]

sklearn tSNE returns a scatter plot like this:

[image]

The data is the exact same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sincere apologies - it was a bug in my code. While the plots do appear differently, they do not differ all that much.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're not doing anything wrong. The algorithm depends on a random starting point, so two runs of the same algorithm will produce different results, unless you fix the seed of the random number generator.

In this case you're comparing two different implementations, so who knows... Neither of the results has any clear structure that the other is lacking, so I have no reason to think anything is wrong.